# Determining optimal zoom level for a geocoded address on Android Map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am developing an Android App. On one of the Views, the user may type an address (not unlikely what one would type in Google Maps) and select the result from a list of reverse geocoded addresses.
Geocoding happens through Geocoder class (android.location.Geocoder class) using the getLocationFromName method.
I then use the Lat/Lng to move GoogleMap camera with CameraPosition.Builder().target(pos), but I have no hint on which zoomLevel to use.

I was requested by the customer to replicate a similar behaviour to what the Maps application on android does, that's usually like:

- if I search for a town like "Milano, Italy", map is centered on Town and zoomed so that most of the town is visible.
- If I search a road (possibly long) without a number, for example "Viale Fulvio Testi, Milano, Italy", map is zoomed on the road, most of the time making the whole road (or a large part of it) visible on the screen.
- If I add also the street number (e.g. "Viale Fulvio Testi 1, Milano, Italy"), zoom may even be a bit bigger. *

I have no marker on the map, neither I have to show current user position. Just the typed location.

Any suggestion on how to replicate GMap behaviour?

It seems like Google Maps can associate a "Region" to the given address, determine a sort of "bounding box" of the region and then ensure that the region is entirely visible on the map, but at the moment it seems I can't figure out any region associated with the result.

Other idea coming to mind (quick and dirty) is checking the various android.location.Address fields (featureName, subLocality, locality, ...) associating a zoom level to each one and determining zoom level based on which one is present, but this could be imprecise: looking for small towns may result in zoom being to big and otherwise, big towns may not fit in the screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), which returns the bounding box you are looking for, e.g.:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Viale+Fulvio+Testi,+Milano,+Italy&sensor=false

returns

```
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 45.52959160,
              "lng" : 9.21414790
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 45.50122050,
              "lng" : 9.197628699999999
           }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks. Think it's probably the solution to go, but I wanted to avoid using other APIs not exposed via Android classes. I don't think I may incur into the API usage limits, but if it happens I may be blocking numerous terminals at once...

Comment: @LMollea This API usage limit is per IP.

Comment: I know. But on a mobile network there's always the risk of devices IP being NAT-ted and Google seeing a limited public IP range...

Comment: @LMollea There is not much you can do about it apart from buying business license or finding other web api for this. I think Geocoder uses the same API with the same limits.

Comment: Maciej's suggestion is good. You might want to query the Geocoding API from your own servers - which is also great because you can send down only the necessary information to your mobile app and perform server-side caching. Without a key, the limit is 2,500 geocodes a day.